# Why use normal, @2x and @3x size images in iPhone when you can use only @3x and set the constraints in different size classes?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I am just confused about this topic.

Comment: I think you need iOS 8 to have it look for `@3x`. `@2x` will be used quite a few versions back. The overhead to downscale should be quite small. So you can probably get rid of the "normal" image at least.

Comment: Also consider that the different sizes may not simply be the same image scaled down - you may want to use a simpler image for the normal or even `@2x` image than you use for `@3x`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000740/supporting-ipad-non-retina-with-retina-images-only and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770958/not-including-non-retina-display-images-in-an-iphone-project?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

Resizing images has a couple of costs including:

Scaling images is an imperfect process. A 3x image scaled to 1x pixel density can have visual artifacts or fail to communicate it's purpose to the user effectively.

Scaling images requires you to load the full size image on older devices with less memory and computing power available to perform those operations which can lead to slower performance. Especially during animations like scrolling views.

As always consider if these are concerns for your specific use case and act accordingly.

Comment: I agree with you it will be extra overhead to processor and memory. But with thilo's comment above I am confused will it really matter?

Comment: Even if the OP were ready to afford the extra processor cost of resizing the image at runtime and the memory pressure of loading an image larger than needed, performing linear scaling to less than 50% of the original size introduces noticeable artefacts t most images AFAIK.